# redux-form: passing initialValues by mapStateToProps as 2nd argument is not working

Tags: redux-form

I was looking how to pass the initialValues to my form:

I found in the redux-form documentation to pass the mapStateToProps as the 2nd. ref: https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.5/examples/initializefromstate/

So i tried the below:

```
IngredientForm = reduxForm(
{ 
  form: 'ingredient',
  validate,
  enableReinitialize : true
},
(state) => {
    return {
        initialValues : state.ingredients.data)
     }
}
)(IngredientForm)
```

Here is mapStateToProps as the second argument. But i found that initialValues in not passed to props.

Then i searched and found the below way of adding mapStateToProps  which worked:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        initialValues : state.ingredients.data
     }
}

 IngredientForm = connect( mapStateToProps )(
      reduxForm(
      {
        form: 'ingredient',
        validate,
      }
      )(IngredientForm)
 );
```

Why the 2nd argument way is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the example you've linked, you can see that it also provides `mapStateToProps` as an argument to `connect`, not `reduxForm`:

```
// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }               // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm)
```

[Source](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.5/examples/initializefromstate/) for the above.

Comment: Yes, I overseen it then. It took me lot of time.